# How to achieve the same effect like the unlock slider in the welcome screen of iPhone OS?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-animation, core-graphics

I need to do something similar, where an animation highlights the text of a button to show that it must be slided to do something. Just like that unlock thing on the iPhone. How is that done? Is there a tutorial how to achieve this effect?

Comment: Careful, Apple has that swipe movement patented (according to their recent legal filings). I'd hate to see you get sued...

Comment: It sounds like OP is referring to the highlight animation (looks like a spotlight panning across the text) and not to the actual slide-to-unlock functionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The searchlight-effect is also included in the three20-project, if you are planning to build such a control on your own.

Answer (score 2):

There's a project here: http://altosdesign.com/iphonesdk/SlideToCancel.zip which has the effect you're after.